# How do I get my localhost to work for my android emulator?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I am using a Django server, and a react native frontend (with expo).

I can access the server fine on my browser and with the iOS simulator (I use a Mac), however, on the android simulator, I get a network error, and it can't connect to my server.

Here is the react native code that works fine:

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/events/?featured=true", {
      method: "GET",
    })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add the localhost as proxy in package.json and use the fetch call as fetch("api/events/?featured=true"))

Comment: Where is your sever running? And where is your Android emulator running? And where is your browser running? And you do not tell us which network error?

Comment: `Here is the react native code that works fine:` Fine. But then.. where is the code you use on Android that does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I added my machine's IP to ALLOWED_HOSTS in my Django settings.py
2. Then I ran my server on my machine's IP with the command: ./manage.py runserver XX.XXX.XX.XX:8000 (replace the X's with your machine's IP)
3. And then I changed all my react native functions to the following:

```
const root = "XX.XXX.XX.XX"
  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch(root+"api/events/?featured=true", {
      method: "GET",
    })
```

Replace the X's in the above code with your machine's IP-address.

Answer (score 2):

**Use 10.0.2.2 to access your actual machine for the android emulator.**

when you use the emulator, localhost (127.0.0.1) refers to the device's own loopback service, not the one on your machine as you may expect.